For passing Jwt Token for login
In ASP.NET Core Web API, I want to create an API for login by using JWT token.
 "AppSettings": {
   "Issuer": "",
   "Key" : "ThisIsMySecretKeyWith32BitLetters"
 }

I need to pass the token for user and this is my login API.
 [HttpPost("login")]
 public IActionResult Login(Login user)
 {
     var person = _mydb.Login
                       .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Email == user.Email 
                                            && c.password == user.password);

     if (person != null)
     {
         return Ok("Login successful");
     }
     else
     {
         return BadRequest("Authentication failed");
     }
 }


If I've understood correctly, this is your secret key for forging the JWT token. If that's the case, you can create a JwtSettings class, for example:
namespace Project.Helpers;

public class JwtSettings 
{
    public string Issuer { get; init; }
    public string Audience { get; init; }
    public string SecretKey { get; init; }
}

And your appsettings.json:
{
  "JwtSettings": {
    "Issuer": "YourIssuer",
    "Audience": "YourAudience",
    "SecretKey": "YourSuperSecretKeyForJwtToken"
  }
}

Then you can retrieve the values from your appsettings.json in a jwtSettins object from IConfiguration:
namespace Project.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ProtectedController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public ProtectedController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;   
    }

    [HttpGet("data")]
    public IActionResult GetData()
    {
        var jwtSettings = _configuration.Get<JwtSettings>();
        
        var secretKey = jwtSettings.SecretKey;

        return Ok(new { Data = "This is data" });
    }
}

It sounds like you want to implement the authentication method, but ASP.NET Core already has tools for this issue. The JWT Token is not the same as the secret key.
For example this link
Have a nice code
